# JavaScript's try-catch is failing on typeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, try-catch

Just saw this error today on our application. We have a small box on top right of the webpage. It gets updated every minute. What it does is make a jsonp call to each of our hospital partners via intranet and pulls the latest news. The issue doesn't happen often. I actually found out why the error is happening.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery11020382352269484832883_1441911920555 is not a function
```

This error shows up in console when a jsonp request doesn't get the response from the jsonp service within the time assigned on the jsonp timeout.

I wrapped our endpoint call with try-catch but it is still spitting out that error. I want to get rid of "Uncaught TypeError" and display our own custom error.

Comment: your `try-catch` only wrap the call of the request, not the callbacks

Comment: you should be able to see the stack trace of the error, then you can see where you should put this try-catch

Comment: The stacktrace is directly on the dynamically generated JQueryfunction name that doesn't exist anymore since it's Jquery that created the function name. I think this happens when we don't specify jsonpCallback property in our $.ajax

Comment: So you have your answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it. I recreated the issue while I am in Chrome Dev Tools. The error showed up on a dynamically created function. My confusion is how will I wrap that function if it only gets created during runtime? Are you saying that I should add jsonpCallback?

Comment: seem to be a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8744), I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/3v282yc4/) with a solution found by `e.marin`

Comment: Ok Hacketo, i'm going to try it now. Which part is the bug you're referring to?

Comment: There is a link to the bug in the comment, it's about that it call the jsonpcallback when timed out, but it should not.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working great! Is your code affected by that bug?

Comment: this code is a possible solution (just saw it in the comments of the bug repport, I did not test it in all browsers) . As it know the name of the jsonpcallback function, when error is thrown, it create this function to avoid the error log an destroy it. You can see the bug if you remove the function declaration in the error callback

Comment: Cool! If you want, you can just paste the code so I can give the points to you and mark it as accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use jQuery and an http request is async, you cannot handle this kind of error with a `try-catch`, this would catch only errors for the call of the request, not the entire process.

Some research gave me this link : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8744

Actually the jsonpCallback function should not be called when the request timeout, it appear to be a browser bug : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8744#comment:2 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707154

Someone in the jQuery bug repport ([`e.marin.izquierdo`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8744#comment:34)) gave a possible solution to "handle" this error. (I changed it a little bit removing irrelevant stuff)

```
var auxTime = new Date();
var jQueryCallbackRandom = auxTime.getTime();

var callParameters = {
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    timeout: 5,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { echo: "Hello World!" },
    jsonpCallback: "jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom,
    success: function(){
        console.log("success");   
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log("failed with error: " + textStatus);
        window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = function() {
            window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = null;
        };
    }       
};

$.ajax(callParameters);
```

It create the jsonpCallback in the error listener to avoid the error, but to do this you need to know the name of the `jsonpCallback`.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/3v282yc4/)

Comment: By the way, I was still able to reproduce that error but very rarely. I created a new post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531360/js-exception-is-still-able-to-sneak-in-but-very-rarely-not-sure-why

Comment: @devwannabe as you can see, you used different part of that code in differents scopes, so it can't work the way you were using it, only need to wrap the whole code in a function if you want to make a function