# JS exception is still able to sneak in but very rarely, not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, typeerror

I wrapped the function with setTimeout it will run forever. If you notice on the screenshot, js exception happened after so many times. That is what is happening on our real app too. I am not sure why.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux12xoya/1/

```
    // JSON Request
    var auxTime = new Date();
    var jQueryCallbackRandom = auxTime.getTime();

    var callParameters = {
        url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
        timeout: 2,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { echo: "Hello World!" },
        jsonpCallback: "jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom,
        success: function(){
         console.log("success");   
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log("failed with error: " + textStatus);
            window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = function() {
              window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = null;
            };
        }       
    };

    var timeout = setTimeout(callAjax, 5000)

    function callAjax() {
        $.ajax(callParameters);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(callAjax, 5000)
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9hI.png

Comment: you have to put all variables in `callAjax` ... to makes them locals to `callAjax` scope

Comment: You're using the same `jQueryCallbackRandom` with every request. If any one request takes longer than 5 seconds, you'll start running into conflicts. Stop manually naming the callback and that will stop happening.

Comment: @KevinB see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515179/javascripts-try-catch-is-failing-on-typeerror/32526274

Comment: You didn't look at the code well. the callback name is random always

Comment: No it isn't, you set it once, at the top, and then reused it for every request.

Comment: It is very poor practice to ajax in a timeout. Instead call the timeout in the success or done callback

Comment: The `callParameters` are just initialized once, so they'll be exactly the same on each `$.ajax()` invocation. If you move all that stuff (exception the start-off call to `setTimeout()` inside the `callAjax()` function as @Hacketo suggested, then it will not have those failures. (It will still have timeout errors, because you've set a very short timeout limit.)

Comment: The timeout 2 is to reproduce a bug about jsonp and timeout problem, issue stated in the post I linked in past comment

Comment: I see the error. I'll have to correct the code. However, here in our real app, the callback name is different always but the issue sometime still happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is failing because your timeout is too short. When the request times out, the callback is removed from the window, and then when the request actually finishes, an exception is thrown because the callback isn't on the window. It doesn't happen every time because you're using the same callback name for every request, and sometimes it just so happens to complete while another request hasn't timed out yet resulting in a "success" that wasn't actually a success.

---

Your code was actually pretty close, the root of the issue here is that you didn't give each request a unique JSONPCallback. You simply need to move those variables into the ajax function so that they will be re-created for each request, resulting in each getting it's own auxTime based callback name.

```
// JSON Request
var timeout = setTimeout(callAjax, 5000)

function callAjax() {
    var auxTime = new Date();
    var jQueryCallbackRandom = auxTime.getTime();

    var callParameters = {
        url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
        timeout: 5,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { echo: "Hello World!" },
        jsonpCallback: "jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom,
        success: function(){
         console.log("success");   
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log("failed with error: " + textStatus);
            window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = function() {
              window["jQueryRandom_" + jQueryCallbackRandom] = null;
            };
        }       
    };
    $.ajax(callParameters);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux12xoya/2/

Comment: The objective of this poc is to capture the Uncaught TypeError. Here in our product, our timeout is 60 seconds and it still happens rarely

Comment: The error will always occur if the timeout happens, because this is JSONP. it is unavoidable. If the callback is no longer available to be executed, a typeerror will occur.

Comment: eh, i guess that's what you were doing, you were avoiding it by redefining the function yourself. that was failing because you're using the same callback name for each request.

Comment: Yes Kevin and it's kinda like a hack that i found in jquery.com forum. It is a bug in jsonp

Comment: @devwannabe I don't think it's a "bug" in JSONP. That doesn't even make much sense.

Comment: it's not a bug at all, it's just the way it works. JSONP is in of itself hacky, it isn't an official protocol supported by browsers, instead it's a clever workaround to allow cross-origin transfer of information without the pitfalls of xhr through the use of <script> tags, which are allowed to be cross-origin.

Comment: Pointy, someone mentioned it here. Maybe I misinterpreted it. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8744

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle, it's random now. I'll wait if it will error - http://jsfiddle.net/ux12xoya/5/

Comment: haha, that bug report... *"Expected behaviour: jQuery should correctly cancel the XHR when hitting the timeout."* there's no xhr to cancel.

Comment: Ah OK - it's an browser `<script>` tag implementation weirdness. That's good to know :)

Comment: In our real app, it's really random like my new update or your new code. However, i am not sure why sometimes it still shows the exception

Comment: :) I hope we can make it work even if hacky. Really annoyed why rarely, it still shows the js exception

Comment: I would like to now point that maybe backbonejs fetch and sync is the culprit. Right now, I haven't seen any errors yet on my new fiddle

Comment: My fiddle has been through 120 requests without typeerror, and 2 timeouts.

Comment: In your real code, debug the callback name used and ensure that when the typeerror occurs, it isn't using a previously used callback name. I know you said it's unique, but... if it were then this problem wouldn't happen.

Comment: Yes Kevin, I am doing that and callback name is random

Comment: for example, the fiddle in my answer: If i started two timeouts instead of one, it would be possible for two requests to be sent within the same ms of each other, resulting in non-unique callback names. This is why jQuery uses a timestamp AND an incrementing integer when it generates callback names.

Comment: is my callback name randomizer a bad approach? check this pic - http://i.imgur.com/dzgrMaD.png it's random and the one it will error on is randomized :(

Comment: i'd have to actually see the code. If it's the same as in the question, it's certainly possible for it to be not unique.

Comment: @KevinB looks like the culprit is our global $.ajaxPrefilter which does the retry of the GET request when a request fails. When I turned if off, I haven't seen the js exception for 5 mins now

Comment: Possibly because the error callback doesn't happen until after the prefilter, resulting in the callback added by the prefilter being removed by the timeout? dunno. Definitely going to be some kind of logic/timing issue.

Comment: Got it. I'm glad i found the culprit. I will have to figure out a way because I think that retry feature is needed. Actually, I'm going to propose to delete it :D hahaha especially we are already doing setTimeout to call the same function. If it failed on the first one, wait for 60 seconds since it's going to be called again. What do you think? BTW, it hasn't errored.

Comment: If i was going to add an auto-retry feature, i would do it in such a way that it can be toggled on and off per request. Then you can just filter it to not affect jsonp requests, and problem solved.